# ElasticSearch Installation Through RPM On RHL 5.5

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to install elasticsearch 2.x through RPM.When I run

rpm -ivh elasticsearch-2.1.0.rpm it says

error: elasticsearch-2.1.0.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 signature: BAD, key ID d88e42b4
error: elasticsearch-2.1.0.rpm cannot be installed

I tried to sign RPM by

rpm --define="%_gpg_name " --addsign elasticsearch-2.1.0.rpm

When it asks for the pass phrase i tried with my email and d88e42b4 both but it says Pass phrase check failed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you do it like in the guide: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-repositories.html ?

Comment: Hi Bruno, Yes i followed follwoing 1. wget -qO - https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch 2. rpm --import https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch it says error: https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch: import read failed(-1).

Answer (score 0):

I landed in the same boat today and after digging around a while found that Elastic no longer supports RHEL < 6.

Have a look at the Elastic matrix at https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix.

Also refer the thread https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10843.

The question is nearly a year old but I'm answering it with the hope that a fellow passerby might benefit.